# Comparing Similar Columns for Equality

Tags: sql, equality, inequality

I have a (simplified) table that is structured like so:

```
Table: ItemData

PK | ItemID | StoreFK | Retail
1  | 100101 | 1       | 4.99
4  | 100101 | 2       | 4.99
7  | 100101 | 3       | 0.99
2  | 100102 | 1       | 6.99
5  | 100102 | 2       | 6.99
8  | 100102 | 3       | 6.99
3  | 100103 | 1       | 7.99
6  | 100103 | 2       | 8.99
9  | 100103 | 3       | 9.99
```

I would like to return all the items that have a different retail at one or more stores:

**Returns:**

```
ItemID
100101 
100103
```

- Item `100101` has a lower retail at store `3` then at store `1` & `2` it is returned.
- Item `100103` has a different retail at each store location so it is returned.
- Item `100102` has equality in it's retail at all three stores so it are not returned.

I am not new to SQL, but I am lost as to how to make this inequality check in an efficient manor. What is the best way to check for equality in one column based on groupings on another column?

Comment: What would you do if `retail` in all three stores are different?

Comment: Edited the OP to give an example of that case. Expected/desired behavior would be to return that item.

Comment: @Did you just update the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all due respect to Lieven, I prefer this:

```
SELECT ItemID
FROM   ItemData
GROUP BY
       ItemID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Retail)>1
```

Comment: Though all answers worked with the sample data provided in OP, this was the *only* answer that returned the desired results with my **actual** database data.

Comment: I am not sure why this would give different result from Lieven's answer. I just put it because it is faster. If results are indeed different, that fact deserves a separate question.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution I can think of would be to just compare the average of each `ItemID` with the maximum *(or minimum for that matter)* of each `ItemID`

**The SQL Statement would be something like**

```
SELECT ItemID
FROM   ItemData
GROUP BY
       ItemID
HAVING MAX(Retail) <> AVG(Retail)
```

*Note that if `retail` is nullable there are scenario's this method fails.*

See this [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/1948)

Comment: `Store` is not a table... can you select `FROM` a Column?

Comment: @awashburn - You didn't tell us the table name so I used `Store` as it made sense to me. Just replace it with your actual tablename.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I think your `WHERE` needs to be a `HAVING`. But nice solution.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev - thx for catching that. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers +1 it's simple and **syntatically sugary**.

Answer (score 2):

Another method: But I still love @Liven's answer :) My query **tells you number of different prices** as well.

```
select x.itemid, count(x.storefk) from (
select a.* , 
row_number() over 
(partition by a.retail order by
                   a.itemid desc) as r
from retailers a)x
group by x.itemid, x.r
having count(*) > 1
;
```

Results: as per OP's updated question and data.

```
| ITEMID | COLUMN_1 |
---------------------
| 100101 |        2 |
| 100103 |        3 |
```

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9c6f/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
  FROM ItemData
  WHERE itemID IN ( SELECT itemID
                      FROM ItemData
                      GROUP BY itemID
                      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Retail) > 1
                  )
```