# Return multiple row's column values as columns of linked item

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

I have a (simplified) table that is structured like so:

```
Table: ItemData

PK | ScanCode | StoreFK | Retail | ReceiptAlias
1  | 100101   | 1       | 4.99   | Milk
4  | 100101   | 2       | 4.99   | Milk
7  | 100101   | 3       | 0.99   | Milk
2  | 100102   | 1       | 6.99   | Eggs
5  | 100102   | 2       | 6.99   | Eggs
8  | 100102   | 3       | 6.99   | Eggs
3  | 100103   | 1       | 7.99   | Bread
6  | 100103   | 2       | 8.99   | Bread
9  | 100103   | 3       | 9.99   | Bread
```

I can use the following SQL query to get the following return results, which shows all the items that have a different retail at one or more stores: [see this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287188/comparing-similar-columns-for-equality)

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT   im.INV_ScanCode     AS ScanCode,
         name.ItemData AS im
GROUP BY ScanCode, Receipt_Alias
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT im.Retail) > 1
ORDER BY ScanCode
```

**Current Return Results:**

```
ScanCode | Receipt_Alias 
100101   | Milk
100103   | Bread
```

I would like to return all the items that have a different retail at one or more stores **AND** the retail at each store location:

**Desired Return Results:**

```
ScanCode | Receipt_Alias | Str_1 | Str_2 | Str_3
100101   | Milk          | 4.99  | 4.99  | 0.99
100103   | Bread         | 7.99  | 8.99  | 9.99
```

How would I change my SQL query to include the retail at each store location?

Comment: You're looking to transpose rows to columns (pivot). You should try to do this on the application level if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  ScanCode as ItemID,
        ReceiptAlias,
        MAX(CASE WHEN StoreFK = 1 THEN Retail ELSE NULL END) Store_1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN StoreFK = 2 THEN Retail ELSE NULL END) Store_2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN StoreFK = 3 THEN Retail ELSE NULL END) Store_3
FROM    ItemData
GROUP   BY ScanCode, ReceiptAlias
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT Retail) > 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e98a/4)

Comment: This returns all the items, not just the items with retail differing at one or more store locations. See the link to the other SO question.

Comment: To prevent return errors, I changed `ELSE NULL END` to `ELSE 0 END`. I suggest future readers do the same!